# Issue: Shutterbug Screenshot create a new folder for each screenshot instead of keeping them in 1 folder

Tags: java, selenium, screenshot, fullscreen

[image]

I have below code to capture the screenshot with Shutterbug. but it creates the folder and store the screenshot in the folder. Can someone help me to identify the issue? Ideally, i would like to save all the screenshot in one folder.

```
public class CaptureScreenshot {
public static void Screenshot(WebDriver driver,String screenshotName) throws IOException {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy-hhmmss");
        Date date = new Date();
        String screenshotNameFormat = screenshotName + " "+ formatter.format(date);
     Shutterbug.shootPage(driver, ScrollStrategy.BOTH_DIRECTIONS,500,true).withName(screenshotNameFormat).save("./ScreenShots/"+screenshotNameFormat+".png");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The github page on selenium-shutterbug](https://github.com/assertthat/selenium-shutterbug) indicates that `save()` would only take the directory, not the filename as well:

```
 Shutterbug.shootPage(driver)
            ...
            .withName("home_page")
            ...
            .save("C:\\testing\\screenshots\\");
```

So in your case it should be

```
Shutterbug.shootPage(driver, ScrollStrategy.BOTH_DIRECTIONS,500,true).withName(screenshotNameFormat).save("./ScreenShots/");
```